# PHP MYSQL Multiple If Statements for Multiple UPDATES

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone tell me what is wrong with these IF statements?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $dropship = $unitid['id'];
    $jumpship = $_POST['jumpship'];
    $dsdest = $_POST['planet'];
    $dslz = $_POST['landingzone'];
    $dsmission = $_POST['mission'];
    $ds1 = mysql_query("SELECT id, ds1 FROM gc3025_game_jumpships WHERE `id`='$jumpship'");
    $ds2 = mysql_query("SELECT id, ds2 FROM gc3025_game_jumpships WHERE `id`='$jumpship'");
    $ds3 = mysql_query("SELECT id, ds3 FROM gc3025_game_jumpships WHERE `id`='$jumpship'");

    $dist_loc_get2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gc3025_dist_game WHERE `planet`='$dsdest' AND `districtid`='$dslz'");
    $distloc2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($dist_loc_get2);
    $newdist = $distloc2['g_district'];
    $ds_name_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gc3025_game_dropships WHERE `id`='$dropship'");
    $ds_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($ds_name_get);
    $dsname = $ds_name['unit_name'];

    $dest_name_get = mysql_query("SELECT gc3025_planets_game.Game, gc3025_planets_game.owners, gc3025_planets_game.g_planet, gc3025_planets_game.Planet_id, gc3025_planets_id.planet_name  FROM gc3025_planets_id JOIN gc3025_planets_game ON gc3025_planets_id.id = gc3025_planets_game.Planet_id WHERE `g_planet`='$dsdest'");
    $dest_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($dest_name_get);
    $destname = $dest_name['planet_name'];

    $dsdz_name_get = mysql_query("Select gc3025_dist_game.districtid, gc3025_dist_game.g_district, gc3025_dist_labels.id, gc3025_dist_labels.dist_name FROM gc3025_dist_game JOIN gc3025_dist_labels ON gc3025_dist_game.districtid = gc3025_dist_labels.id WHERE `g_district`='$newdist'");
    $dsdz_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($dsdz_name_get);
    $dsdzname = $dsdz_name['dist_name'];

    $dsmission_name_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gc3025_movement_dropdowns WHERE `id`='$dsmission'");
    $dsmission_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($dsmission_name_get);
    $dsmissionname = $dsmission_name['mission_type'];

    if ($ds1 == 0){
    mysql_query ("UPDATE `gc3025_game_jumpships` SET `ds1` = '$dsname', `ds1dest` = '$destname', `ds1dz` = '$dsdzname', `ds1mission` = '$dsmissionname' WHERE `id`='$jumpship'");
    }
    if ($ds1 == 1){  
    mysql_query ("UPDATE `gc3025_game_jumpships` SET `ds2` = '$dsname', `ds2dest` = '$destname', `ds2dz` = '$dsdzname', `ds2mission` = '$dsmissionname' WHERE `id`='$jumpship'"); 
    } 
    if ($ds2 == 1){
        mysql_query ("UPDATE `gc3025_game_jumpships` SET `ds3` = '$dsname', `ds3dest` = '$destname', `ds3dz` = '$dsdzname', `ds3mission` = '$dsmissionname' WHERE `id`='$jumpship'");
        }
    if ($ds3 == 1){
        echo "This Jumpship is Full!";
      }

    echo "<p>$dsname Loaded on $jumpship going to $destname and to complete $dsmissionname In District $dsdzname!</p>";
```

Hope this is enough.

Basically the table is for a jumpship that carries 3 dropships. I need the if statement to basically If ds1 has a dropship in it then the dropship will be entered to ds2 column. if there is a dropship in ds1 and ds2 then it will update ds3 column. if all three have dropships in them then the echo "this jumpship is full" will post.

Comment: That's probably not enough. Are you getting an error message? Explain what you expect vs what you're getting.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with them. But we don't know what the `$ds1`, `$ds2`, and `$ds3` variables represent in your application.

Comment: No error but not updating the table either. I will update the question so there is all of the info.

Answer (score 0):

Function `mysql_query` returns [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), and you must use `mysql_fetch_assoc` for data extraction. Besides, data inside the query should be [properly escaped](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

```
$ds_query = mysql_query(sprintf(
  "SELECT ds1, ds2, ds3 FROM gc3025_game_jumpships WHERE `id`='%s'",
  mysql_real_escape_string($jumpship)
));

$ds_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($ds_query);

if (!$ds_result['ds1'])
{
  mysql_query(sprintf(
    "UPDATE `gc3025_game_jumpships` " .
    "SET `ds1` = '%s', `ds1dest` = '%s', `ds1dz` = '%s', `ds1mission` = '%s' " .
    "WHERE `id`='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($dsname),
    mysql_real_escape_string($destname),
    mysql_real_escape_string($dsdzname),
    mysql_real_escape_string($dsmissionname),
    mysql_real_escape_string($jumpship)
  ));
}
elseif ($ds_result['ds1'])
{
  // and so on  
}
elseif ($ds_result['ds2'])
{
  // and so on
}
```

Comment: Okay the first two UPDATEs work but the ds3 for some reason which is identical to ds2 isn't. The echo works but none of the info ends up in the table.